# Add migration with Required attribute on model class in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a model done in EF that is already created. Now i found that i need to add a new model class to my model and it should be required. See example here

```
public class MyBox
{
  public long ID{get;set;}
    .
    .
    .
  //this is added later
  [Required]  
  public virtual MyBoxDimension Dimensions{get;set;}
}
```

How can i add a migration such that my `MyBoxDimension` has a new default object/value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question I'll provide my own answer

The problem I had was that I thought that migrations could give a default value for reference properties. 
The solution was to add a new migration that would create a `MyBoxDimensions` table and then in the `MyBox` class constructor create a new instance of `MyBoxDimension`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add required attribute to your complex type because complex types are always **Required** ([more info](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types)):

```
var user = new MyBox()
{
    Dimensions = new MyBoxDimension()
};
```

By the way, You can add migration simply by:

```
add-migration FirstMigration
```

Then you can update your database this way:

```
update-database -Verbose
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that i have virtual on all complex types. When I query EF   which is backed by a DB I indeed can get null values on properties that are not set and not required. So I'm not sure what you/your link means by complex types are always required...

Comment: Okay, I think I see now that I used the wrong term. I don't use the [ComplexType] attribute so I have 'complex type' just another model class (or what ever you call it)